# Automatic switch to backup database on fail

Tags: plugins, database, mysql, hyperdb

We have a setup where the WordPress's MySQL database is replicated to a secondary MySQL server in case the primary fails. Are there any plugins or methods which would automatically switch to the secondary database server if the first one is unreachable ?

PS. Tried Hyper-DB but we don't exactly trust it since development on it stopped a while ago.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HyperDB is awesome. You shouldn't worry about its dev date (which by the way, its being done by Automattic - the team behind WordPress).

HyperDB has some bigger advantages like spreading read/writes across servers and splitting them and its mostly used for such purposes (bigger scales).

In your case, I would go for a VIP VPS that would run **Heartbeat**, or a **Failover service**, since I do understand that your scope is HA and not Load Balancing.